# Errors Attaching Tempfile to Email in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, attachment, temporary-files

Have file in `@attachment`. From debug:

```
"datafile"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x3eee9c0        @original_filename="filename.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"datafile\";   filename=\"filename.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/.../RackMultipart20121026-2452-g369hf>>,
```

It was uploaded via a user form.

I'm trying to attach it to an email:

```
...
attachments[@attachment.original_filename] = @attachment
mail(:to => "email@email.com", :subject => "test", :from => @fromaddress)
```

Which errors:

> undefined method `length' for #

I have also tried

```
attachments[@attachment.original_filename] = @attachment.tempfile
```

Which errors:

```
undefined method `[]' for #<Tempfile:0x5629e48>
```

`@attachment.original_filename` returns the proper filename ("filename.jpg" in example)

Anything obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you save the uploaded file to some place, it's a bit limited, what you can do with it (for security reasons - you are supposed to validate the upload and then store the file).

But you should be able to `read` the file:

```
attachments[@attachment.original_filename] = @attachment.read
```

Note: I haven't tested this, maybe you need to read from the `@attachment.tempfile`

Comment: Worked perfectly. I knew I was just feeding the wrong kind of data to mail().